# Can I extend an xsd element whose namespace is blank?

Tags: xml, xsd

I've got a schema that i don't control.  It looks something like this.  Say it's in a file called `Config.xsd`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns=""
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0">
  <xs:element name="config">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="configSettingOne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Cool.  I want to extend the config element and add some more pieces within the sequence.  I'm stuck.  I think it has to do with the fact that the namespace is blank on that one, but every variation on this that i try has visual studio complaining that something's not right.  Let's pretend this file is called `SpecializedConfig.xsd`.  I can control this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="SpecializedConfig"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/SpecializedConfig.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:include schemaLocation="./Config.xsd"></xs:include>
  <xs:element name="extendedTestConfig">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="config">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="configSettingTwo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Am I operating under some fundamental misunderstanding here?  Or can this / can this not be done?  Thanks!

Comment: If it is in fact to do with namespaces, the answer will involve your new schema having elementFormDefault="qualified" and/or no default namespace, or failing that, making an explicit 'no namespace' namespace. Sorry, I won't have the chance to work this into an actual answer today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for a start "config" and "Config" are different names.

The next problem is that you don't extend elements, you extend types. You've given your "config" element an anonymous type, and you can't extend an anonymous type because there's no way to refer to it.

So start by using a named type:

```
<xs:element name="config" type="configType"/>
<xs:complexType name="configType">
```

and then you can extend it:

```
<xs:element name="extendedTestConfig" type="extendedConfigType"/>
<xs:complexType name="extendedConfigType">
   <xs:extension base="configType">
```

I don't think it has anything to do with namespaces.

Comment: Ah!  Good point on the capitalization.  I'll go work through the rest of it - if the end result needs to be modifying the base type, then I'll have to use something else - that type is outside of my control.  Thanks!

Comment: Oooooookay so now that i've re-read the beginning of what you said, I understand.  Sadly "you can't" is all the answer i need!  Ah, well.  Thanks for helping me understand why!